# For which p>0 does $\sum_{k=5}^{\infty}\frac{\ln(\ln k)}{(\ln k)^pk}$ converge?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

For which p>0 does $\sum_{k=5}^{\infty}\frac{\ln(\ln k)}{(\ln k)^p k}$ converge? What would be the best method for solving such a question? My only clue is the idea that $\ln(\ln k)$ grows more slowly than $\ln k $ alone.

Comment: Looks like Cauchy condensation test. I think you have to use it twice. But you also tagged calculus, so I have qualms if we are allow to use that.

Comment: @Nameless exactly—we don't cover that test. Can't the CCT be proven with the Integral Test? Could "reverse engineering" that a bit help?

Answer (score 1):

Moreover $\frac{\ln(ln x)}{(\ln x)^\delta} \to 0$ for $\delta>0$. So the answer is $p>1$

If $p=1+2\delta$ then you can compare the above series with $\sum \frac{1}{k(\ln k)^{1+\delta}}$. The last series is convergent by Caushy integral test.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Check [Cauchy condensation theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test).

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not covered in my course, so it would not be appropriate justification for my purposes. Thanks, though.

Comment: @monorailpilot: You are welcome. However, it is a good result to know.